# Got celery.exceptions.NotRegistered but celery -A app inspect registered shows that my tasks are registered

Tags: python-3.x, celery, django-celery

I need to fix the problem with django-celery with a Redis as a broker. Celery receives the task, accept it but can't finish with raising an exception that the task is not registered.
celery -A proj inspect registered shows that my tasks are registered.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Attaching screenshots: https://imgur.com/ld3KLVD https://imgur.com/qh9KcDz

Answer (score 2):

I have also run into this problem. You might want to check a few things:

1.) the directory from which you are running the celery application

2.) the directory you supplied to the `include` parameter

Celery is a little bit picky with using full and relative paths when looking for your tasks

Here is an example of what my app looks like:

```
|Dir
|_to
  |_my
    |_app
      |_celery.py
      |_producer.py
      |_tasksfolder
        |_consumer.py
```

In `celery.py`: This is how I provider path to my task

```
celery_app = Celery("some_name"
             , broker="amqp://localhost//"
             , backend="db+YOUR_DB://user:pw@localhost:port/db"
             , include=["tasksfolder.consumer"])
```

And in `/Dir/to/my/app` I execute `celery -A celery worker -l info`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Is that the only Celery worker in your cluster, or you have more? You did not show the entire trace so I am not sure... What I am sure though is that the exception was not thrown on your `celery@a4983e769717` worker! You can check this hopefully by examining this particular worker's log (I hope you are writing logs to a file).

The exception was thrown on a worker that has old code. You can even find which one by examining more carefully the output of the same command you used above: `celery -A proj inspect registered`. Find worker(s) that *does not have run_saving_aggregate_data* registered. At least one of them does not.

PS. you do not have to use the screenshots, you can paste the text into a pre-formatted block...